# android background broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-service

Do broadcast receivers run on background in static definition (in manifest).Can someone explain it? Also How can I run a broadcastreceiver on background in api 26(oreo) and higher versions.

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenOnOffReceiver"
              android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="myintent"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

}

```
public class ScreenOnOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public final static String SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG = "SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG, " action name : " + action);
}
```

}

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As android O onward background limitation has been enforced , only some broadcast like BOOT_COMPLETED etc are allowed for static registration. Any other should be dynamically register/deregister while app is in foreground.
More info here - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts

Comment: yes I looked at this page but when I implemented  BOOT_COMPLETED action in androidmanifes.İt does not received on background.

Comment: Could you please paste snippet here to know if there is any mistake in code?

Comment: I pasted it above

Comment: Please confirm if you are using permission in manifest as -- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> also the receiver is placed in proper package , i mean ".ScreenOnOffReceiver" should match.

Comment: that is not work .I added RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission.